# How to upgrade virtualbox 4.2 to 4.3 on debian wheezy with apt-get?

Tags: virtualbox, debian, apt-get

I'm running VirtualBox 4.2 and it keeps telling me that 4.3 is available for update. However when I do `apt-get update` and the `apt-get upgrade` I don't get any updates.

My `sources.list` contains `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ oneiric contrib`. I can't remember why it has `oneiric` instead of `wheezy`, but changing that doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [madison](https://qa.debian.org/madison.php?package=virtualbox&table=debian&a=&c=&s=#) unless you are using old-stable (wheezy) you should have the 4.3 version. You may also enable [wheezy-backports](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/#index2h2) repositories.

```
 virtualbox | 4.1.18-dfsg-2+deb7u5         | wheezy                           | source, amd64, i386
 virtualbox | 4.1.42-dfsg-1+deb7u1~bpo60+1 | squeeze-backports                | source, amd64, i386
 virtualbox | 4.1.42-dfsg-1+deb7u1         | wheezy-p-u                       | source, amd64, i386
 virtualbox | 4.1.42-dfsg-1+deb7u1         | wheezy-security                  | source, amd64, i386

 virtualbox | 4.3.18-dfsg-3                | jessie-kfreebsd/contrib          | source
 virtualbox | 4.3.18-dfsg-3+deb8u3         | jessie/contrib                   | source, amd64, i386
=======================================================================
 virtualbox | 4.3.32-dfsg-1+deb8u2~bpo70+1 | wheezy-backports/contrib         | source, amd64, i386
=======================================================================
 virtualbox | 4.3.32-dfsg-1+deb8u2         | jessie-kfreebsd-security/contrib | source
 virtualbox | 4.3.32-dfsg-1+deb8u2         | jessie-p-u/contrib               | source, amd64, i386
 virtualbox | 4.3.32-dfsg-1+deb8u2         | jessie-security/contrib          | source, amd64, i386
 virtualbox | 5.0.10-dfsg-7~bpo8+1         | jessie-backports/contrib         | source, amd64, i386
 virtualbox | 5.0.12-dfsg-1                | stretch/contrib                  | source, amd64, i386
 virtualbox | 5.0.12-dfsg-2                | sid/contrib                      | source, amd64, i386
```

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question, but is it safe to remove 4.2 and then install 4.3? I mean, I have quite few virtual machines each with different config and It would be a pain to recreate that manually :)

Comment: @SiliconMind Depends what VB has done between 4.2 and 4.3, but there should be no problem.

Comment: Damn! After upgrade to 4.3 the bridged network stopped working :(

Comment: This is weird `ifconfig eth1 down` and then `ifconfig eth1 up` in one of the guest systems solved the issue... for all other guests!