# Upgrading VirtualBox using a `.deb`

Tags: virtualbox, debian, upgrade, dpkg

I'm trying to upgrade VirtualBox using a `.deb`:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/downloads/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.12-93733\~Debian\~wheezy_amd64.deb
```

but it fails with:

> dpkg: regarding
>   .../virtualbox-4.3_4.3.12-93733~Debian~wheezy_amd64.deb containing
>   virtualbox-4.3:  virtualbox-4.3 conflicts with virtualbox
>   virtualbox-4.2 provides virtualbox and is present and installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing
>   /home/atc/downloads/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.12-93733~Debian~wheezy_amd64.deb
>   (--install):  conflicting packages - not installing virtualbox-4.3
>   Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   /home/atc/downloads/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.12-93733~Debian~wheezy_amd64.deb

According to searches and documentation, the `-i` flag to `dpkg` should upgrade if it's installed, but as the error suggests that won't work in this scenario.

How do I upgrade the package in this example? I'd prefer not to remove VirtualBox first. Furthermore, I know `rpm` has the `--upgrade` flag for this. Is there something similar in `dpkg`?

Comment: Did you try with ` --update-avail`? Here there is the solution with [apt-get install](http://superuser.com/questions/688117/how-to-upgrade-virtualbox-4-2-to-4-3-on-debian-wheezy-with-apt-get): they report some conflicts between 4.2 and 4.3. So I'm afraid you should remove it before. Remove only `virtualbox` not the virtual machine! :-) If that computer is offline You can always download the packages and install with `apt-get` with a temporary cache directory

Comment: `--update-avail` didnt' help either. It still complained. I'll just have to remove & reinstall.

Comment: AFAIR 'vanilla' virtualbox.org packages are created in such a way, that `virtualbox-X.N` and `virtualbox-X.M` are unrelated (but conflicting), so you _will_ have to remove `*-4.2` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you see tell you that `dpkg` cannot install for a **conflict** with the previous version.

> dpkg: error processing /home/atc/downloads/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.12-93733~Debian~wheezy_amd64.deb (--install): **conflicting packages - not installing** virtualbox-4.3 Errors were encountered while processing: /home/atc/downloads/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.12-93733~Debian~wheezy_amd64.deb

Seldom and with a lot of work it's possible to overcame such kind of conflict doing a *private installation*, in a local directory and for *one user*. I will not suggest to follow that way until you are forced to. I will not suggest because you have to solve the conflicts one by one, *and by hand*, and  it's moreover possible that you have to do it again each time you want to do an update.

**How to update**

Following the instruction you can find for debian based system on the [virtualbox site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), you can download the Oracle public key for apt-secure and install with this command

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

After you added the key[1] you can run

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-4.2  virtualbox
 sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

This should **not affect your actual virtual machine**, even if it's possible you need to update the guest addition for them.

Notes:

1. If you have problem to add the key probably you need to install `dkms` package with
    `sudo apt-get install dkms`
2. It's possible that you need to download and install again the extension pack.
    If you want to do it from command line:

   `VBoxManage extpack install [--replace] <extension pack>`

   You have to replace `<extension pack>` with the path to your downloaded extension pack and to use the option `--replace` in case you have already installed a previous version of the extension pack.